# Connect to Telegram Bot API through HTTP/Proxy with ngrok

Tags: php, telegram-bot, ngrok

First of all, Telegram is blocked in my country. For some reasons I cannot use VPNs, so I'm trying to connect [Telegram's bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) through HTTP/SOCKS5 proxy with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com).

I tested the following methods, but none of them worked:

1. I set up `http_proxy` and `socks5` in ngrok setting file, but PHP still cannot connect to the Telegram API:

   ```
   $url="https://api.telegram.org/botToken/getUpdates";
   $json = file_get_contents($url);
   file_put_contents('json.txt', $json);
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   ```
2. cURL proxy:

   ```
   $url="https://api.telegram.org/botToken/getUpdates";
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050');// Using tor bundler proxy
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   $result=curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
   ```

   returns `NULL`

**Note:** Above scripts only works when I turn on VPN

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Hi Mwthreex, as far as I understand, ngrok makes your locally opened ports accessible from the public Internet. In other words, ngrok allows sending request from Telegram to your service.
In your snippets, you are doing something opposite -- you are trying to send a GET request to the Telegram API URL.
Did you already check that your proxy server is actually working?

Comment: @andrey-dyatlov my http proxy = 94.242.58.108:10010, and socks5 proxy = 127.0.0.1:9050 (tor bundler), i'm sure both of these is working, remember telegram is blocked in my country

Answer (score 1):

use 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050' instead of 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050')
```